# Same data in props and state

Tags: reactjs

Imagine a Table component, which receives rows as its props.

In my opinion, rows represent component's state as well, since different order of rows results in different view presentation.

Is it okay, to have very same property/data both in state and/or props?

Short code sample

```
var TableComponent = React.createClass({


  // ...

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      rows: this.props.rows
    };
  },

  // ...

})

React.render(<TableComponent rows={[...]} />, document.body);
```

Comment: Why make a copy of all the table rows unless you really need to? (And, setting the `rows` property does not make a copy of the array stored in `this.props.rows`, all you've actually done is store a reference to the original array.)

Comment: To OP and @AlpineCoder
Do you mean you would set `state.rows` after the sorting is applied? Since component should not update its props (parent should) I am referencing original array in component's state. Waiting for comment, really :)

Comment: Solved the problem, not referencing rows as part of state.
Now I need to handle dynamically added rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I was too lazy and overlooked ReactJS' official tips, but one of them refers to very same problem ([link](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)).

After reading this I ended up with this solution:

```
var TableComponent = React.createClass({

    /**
     * Initial component state.
     */
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            sortBy: null,
            sortDirection: null,
        };
    },

    setSorting(column) {
        // ...
        this.setState({
            sortBy: column,
            sortDirection: sortDirection,
        });
    },

    /**
     * Sort rows based on sort state.
     */
    applySorting() {
        return this.props.rows.slice().sort((a, b) => {
            // do sorting
        });
    },

    render() {
        var rows = this.state.sortBy ? this.applySorting() : this.props.rows;
        // render table with sorted or original rows.
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common (and as far as I know accepted) pattern for React components to receive data from props and store it in state. The only complication to this becomes dealing with new incoming props (say an ajax add or delete that changes the row set in a parent component) and managing the transforms you've applied to the copy in the state (in other words, if a user has sorted the rows of your table by a column and reordered the state copy of the rows, you probably want that to be reflected in the new state from the incoming props).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I know what you mean. If appending/removing rows after (lets say) AJAX call, rows should be shuffled if sorting is applied prior to rendering, right?

Answer (score 0):

State represents what changes.

You have row data for a table but in the lifecycle of the component, it never changes.

The order of the sorting, or which columns should display or hide etc, this is the table's state.

In your render method you apply to this kind of state to the row data passed in as a property. Your table component can just consider row data to be a static value that it knows how to render in different ways according to it's state.